# Allow a controller method from a non-logged user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorize-attribute

I have a controller where most every method should be restricted to Role=Admin so the class instantiates with:

[Authorize(Roles = Admin)]

Every method takes on this check. I know I can override this attribute method by method so as to permit other user roles but I'd like to remove the Authorization check completely for one of the methods in this class.

What's the syntax for that?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't able to implement Peter's suggested link so I removed the global attribute and added it back to each of the controller's methods except the one I wanted.